# C# save image very slowly when overwriting

Tags: c#, image, save, overwrite

At first, my VS2017 created images fast and smoothly. But when it ran for second time and the images with same filenames already existed, the program paused at `bitmap.Save(...)` step for every 3 times. It spend 5.4 sec to create all 20 *.png files, but 41.4 sec if all the files are already existed in the target directory. I believe it was dealing with file overwriting.

The code is as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(5000, 5000);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    //Draw something here...

    bitmap.Save(i.ToString() + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);                
    Console.WriteLine("Image Saved");
    bitmap.Dispose();
    graphics.Dispose();
}
```

The weird thing is this problem won't happen if I copy the code and paste it on a new project created in another computer. But if that computer run the *.exe file released from my project it will have same problem.

Is it related to somewhere of my Visual Studio environment setting? Thanks!

Comment: ive just run your code and havent seen any performance issues. When you say it paused, how long was the pause for

Comment: Define "very slowly" ? Did you try to delete file prior?

Comment: Try using an absolute path, not one relaive to the exe to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @SimonPrice it pause 5 sec for every 3 loops, and as you say, it supposes shouldn't have any performance problem, but it happened.

Comment: @Sinatr it spend only 5.4 sec to create all 20 *.png files, but 41.4 sec if all the files are already existed. If I delete all the existed files it will run as smooth as expected, but I still curious about why does it only happen on my computer.

Comment: @TaW Thanks for advice, but it seems make no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem results from the Trend antivirus software. After I shut it down, the program back to normal. Probably because the antivirus software was monitoring or scanning the overwriting process and made it become slow.
Thank you guys for reply.